# PSADT To Detect Active MS Teams Call

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-4.0

My first post on this website :)

I have the following script in my PSADT whereby I only want the script to work if users are not in an active Zoom or MS Teams call. The script stops working as expected when a user is on an active zoom call however cannot get this to work when in an active teams call. The script stops working when it detects that the teams app is open in the background and not in a call like zoom.

```
 ## Test if Zoom, Teams or Skype meetings are active
        Write-log "Check for active Zoom or Teams call"
        If (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}){
            If (((Get-NetUDPEndpoint -OwningProcess (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}).Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.LocalAddress -ne '127.0.0.1'} | measure).count) -gt 0) {
                Write-log "Active Zoom or Teams call detected. Exiting script and trying again on next schedule"
                exit-script -ExitCode 1618
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow :)

According to the case of teams; I tested your code on my machine and found that the `if` condition will always match if the app is opened in background and IPv6 is enabled on your machine

This is due to the IPv6 address `::` which represent according to this [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

> all IPv6 addresses on the local machine

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetUDPEndpoint -OwningProcess (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}).Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

LocalAddress                             LocalPort      
------------                             ---------      
::                                       58673          
::                                       54846
```

so you to exclude also `::` with `127.0.0.1`

```
Get-NetUDPEndpoint -OwningProcess (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}).Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.LocalAddress -ne "127.0.0.1" -and $_.LocalAddress -ne '::'}
```

and the code should be:

```
If (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}){
            If (((Get-NetUDPEndpoint -OwningProcess (get-process | where {$_.Name -match "zoom$|teams$"}).Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.LocalAddress -ne "127.0.0.1" -and $_.LocalAddress -ne '::'}  | measure).count) -gt 0) {
                Write-log "Active Zoom or Teams call detected. Exiting script and trying again on next schedule"
                exit-script -ExitCode 1618
            }
        }
```