# Detect if a meeting or a call is currently going in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I would like to be able to detect if a meeting or a call is currently going on in Microsoft Teams.

Is there a way to detect if a call or a meeting is going on in Microsoft Teams using C#?

Comment: I'm unsure about C# but for things such as this, power automate is really useful. https://unitedkingdom.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/ You can also utilise power automate using C# https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/trigger-a-flow-using-c/td-p/616386

Comment: In order to Get real-time Teams meeting events, refer this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/api-references?tabs=json#get-real-time-teams-meeting-events-api

Comment: The question doesn't mention if this is needed to be determined on a local machine or remotely. On a local machine, you can try two things: scan open window titles for things like "Teams meeting in progress", etc, and/or scan open tcp connections as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636225/psadt-to-detect-active-ms-teams-call

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to detect it on a local machine. Intresting, I'll look into `Powershell`, I have never used it before. Is there a way to make `Powershell` calls from a C# application?

Comment: You can detect when Windows goes into Focus mode.  Perhaps that's close enough?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/applifecycle/focus-session?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such API to detect if a call or a meeting is going on in Microsoft Teams.

To achieve your requirements, we recommend you to raise feature request [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Alternatively, you can get real-time Teams meeting events using below API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/api-references?tabs=json#get-real-time-teams-meeting-events-api

The user can receive real-time meeting events. As soon as any app is associated with a meeting, the actual meeting start and end time are shared with the bot.

The Activity object in TurnContext contains the payload with the actual start and end time. Real-time meeting events require a registered bot ID from the Teams platform.
The bot can automatically receive meeting start or end event by adding **ChannelMeeting.ReadBasic.Group** in the manifest.

Meeting Start Event:

```
 protected override async Task OnTeamsMeetingStartAsync(MeetingStartEventDetails meeting, ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(meeting));
}
```

Meeting End Event:

```
protected override async Task OnTeamsMeetingEndAsync(MeetingEndEventDetails meeting, ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(meeting));
}
```

Sample Code [Link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-events/csharp)

Comment: Is there any api out of Teams app scope? Register to Azure might conflict with our company policy...

Comment: Currently there is no API available.